# Reopen-request: question closed but now edited to SO standards

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-closed

I would like to request that this question be reopened: [Compare two files and append the differences at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150765/compare-two-files-and-append-the-differences-at-the-end)

**Justification**

As originally asked, the question was vague and unclear, linking to large external data files and requiring a fair amount of analysis to understand the point of the question. As edited, it now asks a clear and precise question, with a simple example and and a complete description of the expected output.

**What I did so far**

I have followed the steps listed at [How do you reopen a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question):

- I edited the question so that it is much clearer and no longer too broad, in my opinion.

  My mistake: I first did minor edits but only got to a good quality question after several edits, so the reopen reviewers probably didn't see it in its current state.
- I would like to flag the users who cast close votes to ask them for either an explanation or reconsideration, but none of them commented on the question so I cannot actually flag them.
- This meta question is my last resort: ask for reopen here via the "support" tag. In meta.SE, it seems to say use the "reopen-request" tag, but I didn't find one, so I'm hoping putting it in the subject line will do.

Comment: The question wasn't closed as "vague and unclear", but too broad, and I'm inclined to think it still is, has OP made any attempt themselves?

Comment: No, I suspect OP got what they needed from my answer and hasn't been back on the site since. Their last action was accepting my answer. And OK, if the prevailing opinion is that it's still too broad even as edited, I'll just forget about it. Thank you @NickA for voicing that opinion and not just downvoting.

Comment: @NickA We don't require the OP to 'make an attempt' before asking the question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210959/16587

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I notice that you link to your own answer on a question which has several more upvoted answers (and of which there lots of other similar questions). With all due respect I disagree, I don't necessarily want a code attempt, but I want OP to have put some thought into how they'd solve the problem: *["I know that some may disagree here but "gimme teh codez" is not the best way to introduce yourself to a community. A demonstration of effort proves that they're willing to take the time to help themselves first."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179038/394554)*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't understand how it's too broad. It's a well asked question (as edited), scoped to a specific problem; it's about programming; and there's just one answer on the question right now, with no evidence that the community finds it 'broad' by posting lots of answers.  Lots of kudos to [joanis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3216427/joanis) for editing that question into shape.

Well done!

Comment: I appreciate the positive feedback in your answer, as well is the opposite feedback others gave. This question is much more devisive than I expected, with your answer getting as many downvotes as upvotes, and my (meta) question getting 12 downvotes and 4 upvotes. I'm happy the question got reopened but I would understand had that not happened. Thanks for the kudos!