# Question Effort - What's our line in the sand?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

TL:DR: Is lack of effort a reason to close a question?

Over the past few weeks, I've seen conflicting information about whether a lack of effort should contribute to the closing of a question. I've been under the impression since I first became a member that *yes, a lack of effort should be a reason to close a question*. My impression was formed by:

[This Question and its Top Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

> You won't have to contend with a poorly-written duplicate of a better
>   answer that already exists somewhere else on the site. And you won't
>   get frustrated by having your question closed, and the folks reading
>   it won't get frustrated by having to close it.

[The Official 'How to ask a good question' page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

> Search, and research ...and keep track of what you find. Even if you
>   don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to
>   related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding
>   how your question is different from the rest.

However, it was recently pointed out to me, by *very* high reputation users that a lack of effort *"Has NEVER been a reason to close a question"*. Is this strictly true? Is this a unanimous view?

Most recently, I have seen [this as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388573/the-question-was-closed-as-unclear-what-you-are-asking-why) to a question about why a question was closed;

> Lack of Effort has never been a reason to close, but several of the
>   commenters alluded to that and one said: "Show us the code".

The other examples were in now deleted comments, or revised answers. I guess what I want to know is - **where do we really draw the line in terms of the effort expected from an OP?** If there is no visible evidence of some kind of effort put forward in a question, *should* we vote to close it?

Comment: TL; DR; Of course it is. Best outcome is an appropriate duplicate though.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ That's never been a reason to close; though other reasons were abused to try to fit that reason. It's always been a reason to downvote, however.

Comment: I think this is one of those areas where everyone has a different definition of what, "effort" means.  That's going to be a hard thing to ever define consistently, so maybe a focus on effort is misleading; perhaps looking at post quality is a better thing to weigh for closure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @RobertColumbia Not a duplicate. That one was from the point of view of the asker; this one is from the point of view of the curator.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I have a friend who is... Good at stuff. Even stuff she's never done before. It's always risky to challenge her in a competition, because while I might have been playing a certain game for 10 years there's a non-trivial chance she'll still beat me within a few rounds.

Some folks seem to be able to get away without putting much effort in. They seem to be able to walk up to a new activity / game / community / system and just succeed without even trying. Maybe they live a charmed life; maybe their efforts are hidden, their casual demeanor masking years of careful research and practice.

Regardless, what matters is the results: if you can produce a good question with a trivial amount of effort, more power to you! But if you can't...

### The results of effort... And the lack thereof

[I wrote about this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effort/210868#210868), at length, years ago now:

> Folks aren't looking for "effort" because they think displays of struggle are some sort of magic pixie dust, able to turn a terrible, useless question into gold. They're looking for effort because the lack thereof is the most blatantly obvious hallmark of the thousands of terrible, terrible questions asked every day on Stack Overflow.
>
> - Lack of research effort leading to countless duplicates.
> - Lack of effort describing the problem, leading to unclear and misleading questions.
> - Lack of presentation effort, leading to hard to read questions.

**Visible effort by itself is pointless**, even counter-productive. But if a lack of effort leads you to ask a duplicate, unclear or overly-broad question, then you probably should have put more effort into avoiding those problems.

So to answer your question: **we should draw the line at the point where the problems with a question are so severe that it cannot (unclear) or should not (duplicate) be answered.**

#### See also:

- [Should Stack Exchange in general be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effort)
- [How do I handle Triage no-research cases?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301064/how-do-i-handle-triage-no-research-cases/302067#302067)
- [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions/260909#260909)
- [Make it easier to close job shop "gimme teh codez" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308837/make-it-easier-to-close-job-shop-gimme-teh-codez-questions/308842#308842)
- [Recent changes to close reasons on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Thanks, useful information in those links (particularly the third one, a perspective I hadn't previously considered). It's a shame it isn't consolidated somewhere more immediately visible - particularly to newer users.

Comment: I think a similar discussion can be has about drawing the line on ["Too Localized"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go) questions. Low research questions and very localized questions are very often *bad questions*, but knowing for sure that a question has low research or is really too localized is typically impossible.

Answer (score 24):

A question which has demonstrated a lack of effort can manifest the symptoms in different ways.

In general, if a question really doesn't show any effort and is just soliciting opinions or guidance, that's likely **too broad**.

Questions which seem to not really offer a concrete question associated with their question could also be considered **unclear**, since it's quite useful to have an objective with what the OP wants to accomplish at some level.  Clarity helps answerers deliver better answers.

If an asker wants to make it clear that they have code and that they have a problem, then the problem needs to be self-contained.  If it isn't, then you can close it for that applicable reason.

Additionally, if the question treads existing grounds, then the lack of effort was searching (although in some kind of defense, perhaps that is less accessible than we'd like); in that case it should be **closed as a dupe**.

I wouldn't read too much into the blanket rule of, "Lack of effort is not a reason to close".  There's too many associated symptoms with it to take that at face value.

Comment: "Lack of Effort" means calling people lazy.  I doubt that passes muster with the CoC.  Use the other terms you've detailed in your answer instead, like "Too Broad," "Unclear What you are Asking," and "Duplicate Of."

Comment: Two things there @RobertHarvey:  I don't recall calling anyone "lazy" or any variant thereof when dealing with their questions.  I've simply dealt with them, and haven't really read much deeper than the immediate problem.  Second, by definition, saying that someone's question is a duplicate would imply that they're lazy because they didn't search for it; a question which is unclear would imply that they're unable to communicate clearly enough; a question which is too broad would imply that they're not focused.  *All* of those could be considered insults.  *None* of them are what **I** said.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  My fear is that everyone is taking semantics a little too literally and is missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: Maybe not what *you* said, but every time I see this on main, I also see the implied swipe.  It's better to stick to the official close reasons.

Comment: \*scratches head\*  But I *am* using the official reasons, and justifying why I'm doing so here.  I'm saying that the blanket problem is a lack of effort, but 999 times out of 1,000 it can cleanly map to a close reason we have already established.  Not sure where you're going with this now, @RobertHarvey...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388588/question-effort-whats-our-line-in-the-sand/388592#comment722302_388588

Comment: I can explain it in detail, if you like.  The short version: asking "What have you tried" has (to some degree) turned Stack Overflow from a repository of programming knowledge into a troubleshooting forum.  I'd much prefer a well-articulated, tightly-focused "how do I do [this thing]" question, but we can't have that, because "you didn't show your code."

Comment: Yes, and [I admitted to being a part of that eons ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172762/175248), and I've decided to better myself.  I still [actively rail against that phrase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1079354+%22what+have+you+tried%22) since there's better ways to extract that information from someone, but I see the temptation to slip right back into it.  I even believe we have (or have had at some point) a way to automatically delete those comments.  So yeah...I'm still confused, @RobertHarvey.

Comment: "You didn't show effort" is no better than "what have you tried."

Comment: ...you're gonna have to tell me where that's been tacitly stated.  I feel like you're really nitpicking on the semantics here where I'm simply mapping "lack of effort" on to the already approved close reasons.  I suppose the nit may be with my reasoning?

Comment: I'm saying that "no effort" is a red herring.  It distracts from the real problems with the post. The most obvious problem with it is that it is a statement *about the poster,* not the post.  No mapping is required; the close reason already suffice.

Comment: The mapping is the problem, @Makoto. It leads to these awkward situations where folks are voting to close perfectly clear, narrowly-scoped questions as "too broad" because... They think the question should have shown more effort. Lack of effort is bad *when the result **is** too broad* - but deciding that "broad" is a euphemism for "short", a mapping from some other inscrutable evaluation... Ruins the whole thing. After all, what good is effort put into properly scoping your question when the real problem was someone's opinion on your lack of visible struggle?

Comment: I'm not seeing that, @Shog9.  The way I've always operated has been to give questions which are narrow and well-scoped the benefit of the doubt.  The vast majority of the time in which I've had to go down this road has been with questions which were *truly* irredeemable.  I still believe that I'm arguing that a question which lacks effort is a symptom of something we could legitimately close it for, which I outline above.  But, now at least I understand the issue with my response...

Comment: I'm not suggesting that *you* do this, @Makoto - but it has repeatedly been a problem with this sort of "mapping". That "minimal understanding" close reason was never meant to be a "no effort" close reason, nor was "too localized", "too broad", "unclear" or any of the rest - but once folks get into a habit of mapping, it becomes too easy to ignore the purpose, ignore the problems (or lack thereof) and focus on the heuristic.

Comment: @Shog9:  [I was one of the people who celebrated its removal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355290/1079354).  Maybe this is just us talking past one another, but I am acutely aware that what I'm doing is applying some kind of heuristic.  Once people start wanting hard-and-fast rules, that's when the issue really manifests itself.  So, I'm not interested in recommending hard-and-fast rules.  I'm recommending someone actually look *deeper* at the issue.  Maybe "map" was the wrong phrase for it.  But...I can't linger on this for much longer.

Answer (score 9):

The single most important piece of advice I can give is: don't conflate not knowing what to search for with a lack of effort.

When we designed the question wizard (one of the longest discovery periods we've run), we realized that *most* people do indeed search prior to asking a question. They've either searched for several things in Google, or searched on-site, or tried clicking some of the suggested links they saw while asking, or all of that. We dug this up through looking at how folks arrived to the site, a *whole lot* of user interviews, and a survey we ran on an A/B model that came up after folks had asked their first question.

They searched, they just didn't know the words that would surface meaningful information about their problem. Capturing and displaying the search term is something we almost included in the wizard, because it would give folks a really good idea of what kind of experience lens the person was looking through as they were working on the problem.

That doesn't mean they didn't ask a duplicate question, but it's good to wonder if *their* understanding of the problem would be a useful thing to help other people find the right information, and what they should have been searching for all along. So sure, we might mark it as a duplicate, but try to see if it could actually be a *good* question.

Effort in other things? That's way too subjective and I'd really like folks to (as Shog kind of alluded) look more at the implications than the motive, or lack of any. In other words, look at problems with the question, not the asker.

If there's a lot of missing information, or the question is just completely off-topic - it can be put on hold because it clearly meets one of the established criteria we've set up to mark questions as problematic so people looking to answer can optimize their time more productively. That's why we put stuff on hold and ultimately close and delete it if it doesn't improve.

But don't draw the line at effort. Approach stuff with the intent to evaluate if you can and want to answer it. If something is blocking you from doing that, there's a very good chance you can vote to put the question hold for something way less subjective than the amount of perceived effort :)

Comment: One thing I keep in mind: writing a question on Stack Overflow is a whole lot harder than googling a problem if you know what to search for and the answer is easy to find using a simple web search. And when searching, you don't have to wait for someone to look at your question and write up an answer. So it makes no sense someone would ask here if they _did_ know how to search for it and find an answer that way. True _low effort_ is probably very, very rare. Low visible effort, however, is all too common.

Comment: @ErikA: Question askers on Stack Overflow *are not required to demonstrate effort.*  All that is required is that they ask a clear, on-topic, suitably-scoped, answerable question.

Comment: @ErikA Well, unless we didn't have an answer that really worked with the circumstances they just can't control. That could be due to out-of-date answers (a problem we know is getting worse over time) or a very similar scenario that leads consistently several different outcomes, but only one of which we've got documented. I have over 20 years in C, and I think I'm just at that point where I'm sure about it most of the time (or, maybe, I'm still Dunning-Kruger compromised)

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's sort-of my point. Even if a question has low visible effort, the OP has likely invested a lot of effort anyway, because asking an SO question is just not an easy/low-effort way to solve your problems. So we should not dismiss such questions if they are salvageable. On coaching, I've already left a comment, that just doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure to clearly understand some points in this answer. Is the "... we might mark it as a duplicate, but try to see if it could actually be a good question." part implying that we might also **not** close it as dupe, and even maybe answer it? If this is so, I must admit it's quite surprising: I thought this situation was the whole point of closing a dupe: make sign posts all redirect to the same pot of answers. If it is not the intended meaning, could this part be clarified? Maybe just a "so don't forget to drop an upvote if deserved after you closed it." would do.

Comment: Strange...because, on those questions where I have commented 'Please list the search text you used - we may be able to suggest better', I've had 100% result of...   no reply, OP goes silent.

Comment: @RobertHarvey re "are not required to demonstrate effort", the first point in the  downvote tooltip is "doesn't show any research effort", so I'd argue that askers are required to at least drop a line at what they searched, even just so we may understand where they come from to write a better answer.

Comment: @tensibai that’s a reason to downvote, not close. Hence why we don’t have a close reason for “no research effort”. “Required”  == “criteria for post to stay open”. No research effort is not a valid reason to close a question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think we disagree only on semantic, in my point of view "Required" == "criteria for the post to be correctly received", closure is not relevant to my point, Shog's answer explain very well why a real lack of effort leads to closure for other valid reasons.

Answer (score -17):

Lack of Research effort has never been a reason to [close a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210868/16587). It's always been a [viable reason to downvote a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228709/16587), however.

We even got rid of ['minimal understanding'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188067/16587) because it was being abused to mean 'lack of research effort'.

Ultimately we want users to bring their questions here, and we either coach them on editing their questions into shape or we edit their questions into shape to be useful for others to find.  We want this because that google juice is what keeps us relevant to search results, and ensures that the lexicon people are using when they're searching for a problem matches up with the answers we give them. When the question is so out of whack that we can't do either, that's when it should be closed and deleted.

Comment: Eh.. I think people are downvoting George because they dislike his answer. I specifically dislike the coaching part, imo the tools on Stack Overflow are terribly unfit for coaching

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing this more as disagreement.  I won't doubt that there are some people who *would* cast a vote just because it's George, not analogous to how people would cast a downvote *just* because it was another moderator.  But would it be OK with y'all if we just disagreed with this diamond moderator's perspective without it having to be tied to any historical baggage?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that's a bit presumptuous, I for one downvoted it because I disagree with it, [as I've mentioned to George before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387867/reopen-request-question-closed-but-now-edited-to-so-standards#comment716903_387867). IMO users should spend enough time researching their question looking for an appropriate answer that they shouldn't *need* *"coaching"*. By the time they find out their question is not a duplicate there should be some minimal understanding of how to ask, and, as they've researched, they should be able to show that. i.e. Effort.

Comment: All good. Until you mentioned "coaching".

Comment: @Raedwald A coach doesn't take the shot for you, they do however explain what to improve when you take the shot.  The person asking still does the heavy lifting, but if we don't take the role of coaches we aren't going to improve the behavior of the people that come to Stack Overflow to ask questions and receive our advice.

Comment: I feel folks here are reading too much into the word "coaching". It can simply amount to pointing out what is problematic with a question in a way that persuades its author to fix it.

Comment: @duplode Quite right.  We still expect them to do the work; but our part is to give them guidance to understand what to do.